# Update external json file value

Tags: javascript, json

I have an external file with a value 0. I need to be able to increase the value each time this file is accessed?

json file.

```
number = '[{"num" : 0}]'
```

How can I update the value of this external json file from js?

```
var mydata = JSON.parse(number);
alert(mydata[0].num);
//how add +1 to this value and update the external file?
```

Comment: if that is indeed the content of your `json file.` - then it is invalid

Comment: Is this file located on client or server?

Comment: Open a file, read, parse, update, and write, if it is guaranteed that the file is accessible only by your program.

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks. I do get the value in my alert?

Comment: well, then your file contents must be just `[{"num" : 0}]` - not `number = '[{"num" : 0}]'` as you have stated

Comment: @gurvinder372 Thanks. it's available in the clientside

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks. See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hxuofrh7/

Comment: @Becky I don't think it is possible from browser's javascript directly. At best you can generate this file again and give an option to download this file. But that also won't solve your problem. Can you share which exact problem you are trying to solve, maybe we can help you there?

Comment: @Becky - that fiddle **does not read a json file whose content is as you have stated in the question** ... number is a javascript variable whose contents is the string value `[{"num" : 0}]` - I was confused by your question, and now I see why

Answer (score 0):

since you have the file on the server side, so to update the number every time you access the file, you need a server side programming like PHP or python etc. Then you can use ajax get or post request to that file and on request that file php will increase the number.

The way you can send request to the file using jquery:

```
$.get("YOUR_JSON_FILE", function(data, status){
    // response and data you get from server
});
```

you can take a deep look on it in more details in the link below :
[Jquery Ajax Request](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)